# Using an exported function from a Babel-transpiled Javascript file inside a non-transpiled HTML page

Tags: javascript, import, ecmascript-6, babeljs, nwjs

So I'd like to take advantage of modern Ecmascript syntax in a project I'm developing.  I'm using nw.js (https://nwjs.io/) for a server-side NodeJS application.  I've got webpack setup to do the Babel transpiling, and I think everything on that side of things is working correctly and builds my bundle.js file which contains the Javascript code I want to reference.

The problem is, I've got the main HTML file for my application and I want to reference functions inside my bundle.  What is the best way to access exported functions?  I've tried to use require as well as referencing module.exports to reference exported functions in my bundle.js, but none of these seems to work.  I need to be able to have a button click event fire and then call one of the functions in my bundle.

I should add that I realize I can add event listeners in my bundle file itself, but I'd prefer to be able to reference a function directly from the onclick event on my HTML element if possible.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://itnext.io/calling-a-es6-webpacked-class-from-outside-js-scope-f36dc77ea130) might be what you're after.  Essentially you need to tell webpack to export to a library:

```
output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist/js'),
    filename: 'app.bundle.js',
    libraryTarget: 'var',
    library: 'EntryPoint'
}
```

Then you can reference 'EntryPoint' elsewhere.

```
<script src="./dist/js/app.bundle.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function(){
        EntryPoint.run({ name : 'Joe Bloggs' }) 
    };
</script>
```

Code examples are from the link, not my own!  :)